# ?v= to /v/.html 301 redirect using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I 301 redirect traffic from `example.com/?v={youtube_id}` to `example.com/v/{youtube_id}.html` using `.htaccess`.

I have been trying something like this but nothing works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)$
RewriteRule ^\.php$ /v/%1? [L]
```

Comment: Does the URL of the form `/v/{youtube_id}.html` represent a physical file?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules from here....
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /s/?\?v=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /v/%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules from here....
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(v)/(\S+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: @memesgarage, could you please make sure you are mentioning appropriate file eg: I mentioned `index.php` in my rules, you should change it to as per your need file. Let me know on same, cheers.